# Viewflipper not flinging when child view is webview

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a viewflipper whose child are dynamically created, they can be textview or webview. The view flipper flings correctly when child is TextView but doesnt fling when child is webview.

Comment: your views should be of same type suppose if u are using textview directly in view flipper than all should be textview and if u want to use differnet view than use for all dynamic view one parent linear or any other layout view for each added view

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. The problem i faced is in one view i have a webview in another view i have two imageviews in the first view i tried to swap the view is not changing to second view i used touch events to change between the views but that is not happening. Later i used touch event for webview also then i am able to swap between the views.

the code used for swapping in touch event is as follows.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
{
switch (touchevent.getAction())
{
    // when user first touches the screen to swap
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
    {
        lastX = touchevent.getX();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
    {
        float currentX = touchevent.getX();
        // if left to right swipe on screen
        if (lastX < currentX) 
        {
            // If no more View/Child to flip
            if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                break;
            // set the required Animation type to ViewFlipper
            // The Next screen will come in form Left and current Screen will go OUT from Right 
            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);
            // Show the next Screen
            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }
        // if right to left swipe on screen
        if (lastX > currentX)
        {
            if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                break;
            // set the required Animation type to ViewFlipper
            // The Next screen will come in form Right and current Screen will go OUT from Left 
            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_right);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
            // Show The Previous Screen
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
        break;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

Use the same code for your webview setOnTouchListener, so that it may work for you.

Hope so this helps you.

Thanks and regards,
G.Shashank Reddy.